# Qt Creator cannot find cl.exe (VS2012) compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, build, visual-studio-2012

I compiled 3 versions of Qt 5.0.1 respectively:

1- Qt 5.0.1 on VS2012 64 bit

2- Qt 5.0.1 on VS2012 32 bit

did some tests

3- Qt 5.0.1 on VS2010 32 bit

When I did the tests, the compiled version of Qt 5.0.1 64 and 32 had worked very well. Then after compiling with VS2010, the VS2012 compiler wouldn't work anymore in Qt Creator!!! I'm always getting the message:

```
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

And only VS2010 compiler works in Qt Creator.

I do understand that the compiler's path should be in the environment variable PATH. But I have now two compilers. Wouldn't this get them to conflict if they both were in PATH? 
Shouldn't Qt Creator run vcvarshell automatically before compiling to set the correct environment variables?
What should I do? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it. I switched the compiler to VS2012 amd64 rather than x86_amd64, which is not available in VS2012 Express. This got the command prompt of Qt Creator not to find the compiler. So I switched back to x86_amd64 compiler and it worked.

So you can have two compilers together with no conflicts, that's the good news :)